# How to go back to a previous position on a page in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, scrolling

Is it possible to somehow go back to a previous position in a Google Chrome page?

For example, in Acrobat Reader, there is a very convenient shortcut / hotkey `Alt-Left` which allows you to go back to a previous scroll position from anywhere in a document (`Alt-Right` does the reverse). You can even press this combination any number of times and go back to whatever previous position you want...

I googled the topic, but all discussions are about going back to a previous page, not previous scroll position in the same already opened page...

Comment: `alt+right` seemed to work for me on `google-chrome` in Fedora 35

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not supported in Google Doc unfortunately. It's not like an IDE.
More answer: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/36210/how-do-i-go-back-after-click-on-an-internal-bookmark-in-a-google-doc

Comment: But the question was about Google Chrome, not Google Docs. Anyway, it seems this feature is still not available in Google Chrome...

Answer (score 1):

`cmd+LEFT` and `cmd+RIGHT` work on Google Chrome on my macOS.

Answer (score -1):

Try the `shift` key.  For example, `shift spacebar` will take you up one spacebar worth of scrolling.

Comment: I see this answer was voted down, perhaps because it isn't a direct answer to the question (?), but anyway, I appreciated this answer because I was unaware of space / Shift-space as navigation (scrolling) tools in the browser.